# First Aid (Grant 2nd Wind) question

Tags: dnd-4e, skills, healing

Quick question about first aid (grant 2nd wind). The rules say that the target can use 2nd wind *without using an action*, so does this mean I could use this to heal a dying character as long as they still have their second wind?

It seems as though this would be the go to thing to do, as far as first aid is concerned, as long as the target has their second wind. If not then I would use stabilize the dying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, that is exactly what it means.**

The important thing to remember is that the target has to have their second wind available; if they've already used it in the fight, then first aid will *not* allow them to use it again. The purpose of that ability is to let players use their second wind to get back even when unconscious (as long as someone else spends the action for them, by using first aid), *not* to be an extra "emergency" second wind.